# Microsoft exchange web service (EWS) not working when my application is hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials("usrname", "pass#1234")
};

//to add logic for itemview
service.AutodiscoverUrl("emailaddress@test.com");
```

When I'm running the above code in my application hosted on iis , it is throwing an error 'autodiscover service couldn't be located'.

But when I am running the same on visual studio development server it is working fine.

 How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the IIS server in the same domain as the Exchange Server?

Comment: You will btw get the same error if your credentials are wrong.

Comment: i'm using my outlook credentials and iis server is hosted at my desktop only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your auto-discovery; it works perfectly in my application hosted in IIS.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials("usrname", "pass#1234")
};

//to add logic for itemview
service.AutodiscoverUrl("emailaddress@test.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
        var result = false;

        var redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

        // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
        // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
        // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: have you take a loook at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909442/exchange-impersonation-in-service-account-autodiscover-service-couldnt-be-local

Comment: when i run the code using VS dev server it runs fine but when hosting on IIS at my system it is not working. The above link doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons that you could get that error. You need to [enable tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) with all of the Autodiscover-related trace tags turned on, then review what's happening to find the cause. It could be DNS, credentials, firewalls, etc, etc.